# How to use BING Translation API call to translate a sharepoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, machine-translation

I saw an article that states that the Machine Translation Service has been deprecated in Sharepoint Online, however they provided an alternative to use BING Translator API, anyone knows hot to implement BING Translator to my Sharepoint Site?

Comment: hi. Do you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

here is complete instruction how to use bing translator api in SharePoint.

https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics/wiki/Bing-Translator